# How to solve a Bernoulli differential equation with constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across a differential equation:
$$y^{\prime} = a + \frac{4x^3}{y^2}$$ It seems like a Bernoulli differential equation but it has a additional constant. Can someone help me?

Comment: looks like Bernoulli but it's not Bernoulli.

Comment: try to find an integrating factor to make it exact

Comment: so do you have any idea?@Aryadeva

Comment: I just tried to find an integrating factor but failed. @Physor

Comment: are you sure about the question?!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $y=-\dfrac{1}{u}$ ,

Then $y'=\dfrac{u'}{u^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u'}{u^2}=a+4x^3u^2$

$u'=4x^3u^4+au^2$